# What is CServerDocumentEntry and Why is It Erroring?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Im receiving hundreds of errors each day due to this error.  Its happening within the Application Server Logs.

Can someone explain it and maybe how to solve it?

CServerDocumentEntry: Could not fetch modified time for [APPID]. Skipping newest check.